# Intellij Idea - Cannot resolve file for yaml file in Spring Boot Microservices

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, yaml

I've building an example of Spring Boot Microservices.

I have a message showing url cannot be resolved in yaml file in Intellij Idea 2022.2

Here is the screenshot.

[image: Link]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's reported here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-312083/

Adding an 'optional:' prefix is recommended here:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/current/reference/html/#config-data-import